# Overflow error in shift? VHDL

Tags: overflow, vhdl, shift

I am trying to make a Kilogram to Lib conversion, to do this i am using shifters to make the conversion ( I will have an small error due the representation of the output doesn't be fractionary), i found the correct function and values to do the conversion, when I say this I mean my shifts value are correct, if someone wants the conversion function just let me know in the comentaries below.

My problem is: when i put a value bigger than 130 KG the conversion goes wrong, small values then 130 KG works correctly. I am using a input with 16 Bits (Kilogram Input) and a 16 bits output (LB Output).

When this error appears, in the first time, I think was a overflow error in the adders, but all adders doesn't show carry out, so it can't be overflow on the adders. I've tried to use bigger representation in values(32 bit), but the error still appears. I've removed the carry out outputs due this.

Below the codes:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity shift_register is
port (
    i_DIN : in unsigned (15 downto 0);
    o_DOUT0 : out unsigned (15 downto 0);
    o_DOUT1 : out unsigned (15 downto 0);
    o_DOUT2 : out unsigned (15 downto 0);
    o_DOUT3 : out unsigned (15 downto 0)); 
end shift_register;

architecture arch_1 of shift_register is
begin
    o_DOUT0 <= i_DIN SLL 9;
    o_DOUT1 <= i_DIN SLL 5;
    o_DOUT2 <= i_DIN SLL 2;
    o_DOUT3 <= i_DIN SLL 1;
end arch_1;
```

On this part i make the 4 necessary shifts to the conversion work, after this i get the 4 values output and sum into 2 half adders.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity half_adder is
port (
    i_DIN0 : in unsigned(15 downto 0); -- data input
    i_DIN1 : in unsigned(15 downto 0); -- data input
    o_DOUT : out unsigned(16 downto 0)); -- data output
end half_adder;


architecture arch_1 of half_adder is
begin
process(i_DIN0,i_DIN1)
     variable soma:unsigned(15 downto 0);
     variable c:std_logic; 
     begin
          c :='0';
          for i in 0 to 15 loop
                soma(i) := i_DIN0(i) xor i_DIN1(i) xor c;
                c := (i_DIN0(i) and i_DIN1(i)) or ((i_DIN0(i) xor i_DIN1(i)) and c);
          end loop;
          o_DOUT(15 downto 0)<= soma(15 downto 0);
          o_DOUT(16) <= c;
      end process;
end arch_1;
```

I will have 2 outputs, 1 for each half adder, this 2 outputs i sum into a full adder to get the final shift value, the carry out from the 2 half adders are concatenated in the last bit from each output.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity full_adder is
port (
    i_DIN0 : in unsigned(16 downto 0); 
    i_DIN1 : in unsigned(16 downto 0); 
    o_DOUT : out unsigned(16 downto 0)); 
end full_adder;

architecture arch_1 of full_adder is
begin
     process(i_DIN0,i_DIN1)
     variable soma:unsigned(16 downto 0);
     variable c:std_logic; 
     begin
          c := '0';
          for i in 0 to 16 loop
                soma(i) := i_DIN0(i) xor i_DIN1(i) xor c;
                c := (i_DIN0(i) and i_DIN1(i)) or ((i_DIN0(i) xor i_DIN1(i)) and c);
          end loop;
          o_DOUT <= soma;
      end process;
end arch_1;
```

Here i don't concatenate the carry out from the full adder to the last bit of the output because i want to show the carry out if the sum overflow.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity div_register is
port (
    i_DIN : in unsigned (16 downto 0);
    o_DOUT : out unsigned (16 downto 0)); 
end div_register;

architecture arch_1 of div_register is
begin
    o_DOUT <= i_DIN SRL 8;
end arch_1;
```

In the end i divide the sum of the 4 initial shifts to get the converted value.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
entity kg_to_lb is
port (
    i_INPUTKG : in  unsigned(15 downto 0); -- data input
    o_OUTLB : out unsigned(16 downto 0)); -- data output
end kg_to_lb;


architecture arch_1 of kg_to_lb is

component full_adder is
    port (
    i_DIN0 : in unsigned(16 downto 0); 
    i_DIN1 : in unsigned(16 downto 0); 
    o_DOUT : out unsigned(16 downto 0)); -- data output
end component;

component half_adder is 
port (
    i_DIN0 : in unsigned(15 downto 0); -- data input
    i_DIN1 : in unsigned(15 downto 0); -- data input
    o_DOUT : out unsigned(16 downto 0)); -- data output
end component;  

component shift_register is 
port (
    i_DIN : in unsigned (15 downto 0);
    o_DOUT0 : out unsigned (15 downto 0);
    o_DOUT1 : out unsigned (15 downto 0);
    o_DOUT2 : out unsigned (15 downto 0);
    o_DOUT3 : out unsigned (15 downto 0)); -- data output
end component; 

component div_register is 
port (
    i_DIN : in unsigned (16 downto 0);
    o_DOUT : out unsigned (16 downto 0)); -- data output
end component; 



signal w_OUT0 : unsigned(15 downto 0);
signal w_OUT1 : unsigned(15 downto 0);
signal w_OUT2 : unsigned(15 downto 0);
signal w_OUT3 : unsigned(15 downto 0);
signal w_OUT4 : unsigned(16 downto 0);
signal w_OUT5 : unsigned(16 downto 0);
signal w_OUT6 : unsigned(16 downto 0);
signal w_OUT7 : unsigned(16 downto 0);

begin 

u_0: shift_register port map (
                 i_DIN => i_INPUTKG,
                 o_DOUT0 => w_OUT0,
                 o_DOUT1 => w_OUT1,
                 o_DOUT2 => w_OUT2,
                 o_DOUT3 => w_OUT3
                  );

u_1: half_adder port map (
                 i_DIN0 => w_OUT0,
                 i_DIN1 => w_OUT1,
                 o_DOUT => w_OUT4
                  );

u_2: half_adder port map (
                 i_DIN0 => w_OUT2,
                 i_DIN1 => w_OUT3,
                 o_DOUT => w_OUT5
                  );

u_3: full_adder port map (
                 i_DIN0 => w_OUT4,
                 i_DIN1 => w_OUT5,
                 o_DOUT => w_OUT6
                 );

u_4: div_register port map (
                 i_DIN => w_OUT6,
                 o_DOUT => w_OUT7
                 );

o_OUTLB <= w_OUT7;

end arch_1;
```

Here is my main file, where i did all of this, basically I am using the same architecture of the image below, the only difference is the shifts, because i use another values in my conversion function, but with the shifts of the imagem the error still occours.

[image: Main Architecture]

Below the correct conversion:

[image: 110KG conversion]

Like i said in before, an error will exist due the diregarding of the fractionay part. When i input a value bigger than 130KG the conversion goes wrong:

[image: conversion error]

NOTE: In my simulation i didn't put the carry out from the full adder because i already simulated this, and does'nt appears carry out (overflow error) in the simulation, due this i think the error is in the shifts.

Someone knows what this is?

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), since doing so will maybe reveal the problem, and will make it easier for others to help.

Comment: What is missing? I think all of this is necessary to find the problem...

Comment: Actually the error shows up over 127 kg, and it is an accuracy problem with the shift_register (`o_DOUT0 <= i_DIN SLL 9;`). kg values greater than 127 (8 bits or more) left shifted 9 bits drops bits on the floor for a 16 bit value.

Comment: Probably nothing is missing to reproduce the problem, but the point is that some parts probably can be left out...  "Perfection is achieved, not when there is nothing more to add, but when there is nothing left to take away." (Antoine de Saint-Exupery).  The ideas with Stack Overflow is to create a database of reasonable generic questions and answers, that can be applied to a variety of similar programming problems, and asking one-off design questions does not contribute to such a database.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback martin, in my next posts i will remember this.

Comment: And thanks for your comment user1155120, with if i can solve the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was in the internal registers width, when i shift logical 9, for values bigger than 8 bits de output stays in 0 because the shift was to big, the solution for this was use bigger register (32 bits in this case).